# Dispatch thunk from another thunk created with createAsyncThunk from redux-toolkit

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

This is more typescript question, but my issue is specific inside [createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createasyncthunk) method from `@redux/toolkit`. What is the return type from dispatching a thunk action?

```js
const myService = (num: number) => Promise.resolve(num.toString());

const myAction = createAsyncThunk(
  'FOO', myService
)

const myFirstAction = createAsyncThunk<
  string, // return type
  number // param type
>('First', (num) => {
  return myService(num) // calling service directly so OK
})

const mySecondAction = createAsyncThunk<
  string, // WORKS because i'm calling unwrapResult on resolved value
  number, // param type
  {
    dispatch: AppDispatch,
  }
>('Second', (num, { dispatch }) => {
  return dispatch(myFirstAction(num)).then(unwrapResult)
})

const myThirdAction = createAsyncThunk<
  string, // FAILS ?? <- What type to use here
  number, // param type
  {
    dispatch: AppDispatch,
  }
>('Third', (num, { dispatch }) => {
  return dispatch(myFirstAction(num))
})
```

Comment: AppDispatch comes from `export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch` btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, it's

```
ReturnType< AsyncThunkActionCreator<Returned, ThunkArg, ThunkApiConfig> >
```

but, as that type is not exported,

```
ReturnType< AsyncThunk<
  Returned,
  ThunkArg,
  ThunkApiConfig
> >
```

should do the trick.

You can see the sources for this type [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/06c185490974175bcea4573053952c6524973529/src/createAsyncThunk.ts#L272-L281).

Comment: Thank you once again @phry for your answer :)